# Stop the continuation of a flow within a devkit @processor

Tags: mule, devkit

Is there an agreed upon way to stop the continuation of a flow within a devit @processor method? I want it to behave like a filter, where the message is dropped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: define it as an intercepting processor.

```
@Processor(intercepting = true)
public Something foo(..., final SourceCallback sourceCallback)
```